# How to fill missing Rows in DataFrame with values in specific range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am missing some rows in a DataFrame, my range of `date_number` spans from 0 to 50. I would like to create the missing rows, in this case missing the range from 0 to 13 and from 29 to 50. I would like that every missing is filled with the following data:

```
date_number tag_id    price weekday brand_id  sales  stock  profit
XX.X        665237982.0 12. Y.Y     2123.0        0.0  0.0    0.00
```

```
date_number tag_id    price weekday brand_id  sales  stock  profit
14.0        665237982.0 12.95 0.0     2123.0        0.0  128.0    0.00
15.0        665237982.0 12.95 1.0     2123.0        9.0  106.0  116.55
16.0        665237982.0 12.95 2.0     2123.0       29.0  137.0  375.55
17.0        665237982.0 12.95 3.0     2123.0       24.0   88.0  310.80
18.0        665237982.0 12.95 4.0     2123.0       27.0   35.0  349.65
19.0        665237982.0 12.95 5.0     2123.0        2.0    2.0   25.90
21.0        665237982.0 12.95 0.0     2123.0       14.0  312.0  181.30
22.0        665237982.0 12.95 1.0     2123.0       12.0  455.0  155.40
23.0        665237982.0 12.95 2.0     2123.0       12.0  450.0  155.40
24.0        665237982.0 12.95 3.0     2123.0        8.0  450.0  103.60
25.0        665237982.0 12.95 4.0     2123.0       11.0  427.0  142.45
26.0        665237982.0 12.95 5.0     2123.0        9.0  401.0  116.55
27.0        665237982.0 12.95 6.0     2123.0       19.0  377.0  246.05
28.0        665237982.0 12.95 0.0     2123.0       12.0  343.0  155.40
29.0        665237982.0 12.95 1.0     2123.0        9.0  314.0  116.55
```

Comment: Try developing a solution using something like `pd.Series(range(50)).isin(df.date_number)` to select the numbers that you want to add. Show some code where you get stuck.

Comment: Question doesn't note what the weekday should be in the filled in rows.